# Laravel PUT route results in a 404

Tags: php, rest, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm trying to make a put route for an edition form in my app.

Here's the route I created :

```
Route::put('admin/monitor/{$id_monitor}', 
    array(
        'as' => 'admin/monitor/update', 
        'uses' => 'MonitorController@update'
    )
);
```

The `edit.blade.php` :

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('admin/monitor/update', $monitor->id_monitors), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}
// Stuff related to the inputs etc.
{{ Form::submit() }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And finally the `update` function :

```
class MonitorController extends BaseController {
    // Some other methods
    public function update($id_monitor) {
        echo "Form submitted !";
        die;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I submit the form, I'm getting a `NotFoundHttpException`. Could someone explain to me what did I miss ?

Thanks !

Comment: From what I remember you need to have a hidden field with name of "method" and value of "PUT"

Comment: @Ian This is handled automatically by Laravel

Comment: Is your monitor id "id_monitors" or just "id"?

Comment: It's `id_monitors` (don't blame me for the naming convention, I didn't chose it :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
Route::put('admin/monitor/{$id_monitor}',
```

to

```
Route::put('admin/monitor/{id_monitor}',
```

Comment: you bested me by 2 sec :p

Comment: Well, don't know what to say... Hopefully this is friday ! Thank you :)